# QTcreator как подключить libharu

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, makefile

Скачал библиотеку libharu для работы с `.pdf` с их сайта http://libharu.org. После распаковки – в папке нету ни одного файла `lib*.a` или `.lib`.

Как я понял, ее нужно собрать/скомпилировать. Везде в документациях и вопросах пишут одно и то же:

> Unpack the libharu package, using the command prompt.
>
> 1. Microsoft VC++ Compiler
>
> ```
> NMAKE -f script/Makefile.msvc
> ```

Куда это вводить? Что за мейкфайлы (пытался читать)? Как ее собрать?

Comment: ОС: windows 10
Qt Creator 4.12.2
Based on Qt 5.14.2 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1144368/394322

Comment: @вася я же написал, что читал их документацию, что видел эти команды. Я не могу понять куда их вводить? в cmd? или в QT где-то?

Comment: *Куда это вводить* - в [command prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs), *что за мейкфайлы* - мейкфайлы для [nmake](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @user7860670
Спасибо за ответ. Вот попробовал запустить в Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.6.2

Получил вот это
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'src\hpdf_utils.obj'
Stop.

Comment: После распаковки вам нужно прочитать readme, и собрать либу по инструкции, а потом уже ее подключать к своему проекту

Comment: попробовал собрать ради интереса - видимо вы собираете перейдя в папку script, а не из корневой. Кроме того, там предварительно необходимо собрать зависимости - zlib и libpng, и зависимости этих зависимостей...

Comment: Но ведь изначально они дают команду NMAKE -f script/Makefile.msvc
что я так понимаю означает сборку из скриптс. Откуда и что тогда нужно собирать и что за зависимости?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте коммандную строку, перейдите в каталог, где распаковали файлы библиотеки и выполните команду:

```
nmake -f script/Makefile.msvc
```